# Disnake: delete ephemeral interaction response

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a bot that allows users to play games with slash commands. The bot responds with ephemeral messages. To keep it tidy, it would like to remove some responses (e.g. if the user doesn't react after a few minutes). However, I'm struggling to remove ephemeral messages.

The bot is sending a response with:

```
await inter.send(file=file, embed=embed,components=components, ephemeral=True)
```

If ephermal=False, the following code deletes the bot response:

```
await inter.delete_original_message()
```

However, if ephermal=True, I get the following error when trying to delete the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                      
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/slash_core.py", line 680, in invoke                                                 
await call_param_func(self.callback, inter, self.cog, **kwargs)                                                                                     
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/params.py", line 817, in call_param_func                                            
return await maybe_coroutine(safe_call, function, **kwargs)                                                                                         
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/disnake/utils.py", line 580, in maybe_coroutine                                                          
return await value                                                                                                                                  
File "/code/cogs/game.py", line 271, in game                                                                                                
await game(                                                                                                                                    
File "/code/cogs/game.py", line 189, in game                                                                                               
await inter.delete_original_message()                                                                                                               
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/disnake/interactions/base.py", line 526, in delete_original_message                                      
await deleter                                                                                                                                       
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/disnake/webhook/async_.py", line 222, in request                                                         
raise NotFound(response, data)                                                                                                                      
disnake.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message
```

Is there another way of deleting ephemeral messages?

The relevant documentation section: https://docs.disnake.dev/en/latest/api.html#disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction.delete_original_message

Edit:
whentrying to set the `delete_after` property of the ephemeral message I get:

```
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: ephemeral messages can not be deleted via endpoints
```

I guess this is a hint that discord does not allow ephemeral messages to be deleted via API by any means.

Comment: Yoda's Voice: "Answered your own question you have. Mmm!"

Answer (score 1):

You figured it out, but overall the Discord API does not allow you to delete an ephemeral message. The best you can get is changing the message content.